# Poynting vector and intensity of a signal

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, fourier-transform, poynting-vector, intensity

Given a plane monochromatic electromagnetic wave propagating in $x$ direction, with associated electric and magnetic fields of the form:

$\overrightarrow{E}(x,t)=\overrightarrow{E_0}\cos(kx-\omega t), \quad \overrightarrow{H}(x,t)=\overrightarrow{H_0}\cos(kx-\omega t)$

we can define the wave Poynting vector as (given that the electric field, the magnetic field and the direction of propagation $\hat{x}$ are mutually orthogonal):

$\overrightarrow{S}(x,t)=\overrightarrow{E}(x,t) \times \overrightarrow{H}(x,t)=E_0H_0 \cos^2(kx-\omega t)\hat{x}$

which represents the power $W$ per $m^2$ carried by the wave at the time $t$ in position $x$. Now, using the well known electromagnetic relation $H_0=\frac{nE_0}{Z_0}$, where $n$ is the refraction index and $Z_0=\sqrt{\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}}$ is the void impedance, we have that:

$\overrightarrow{S}(x,t)=\frac{nE_0^2}{Z_0}\cos^2(kx-\omega t)\hat{x}$

Taking the mean over the time period $T$ we finally have:

$\langle \cos^2(kx-\omega t) \rangle=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T \cos^2(kx-\omega t)\text{d}t=\frac{1}{2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \left\langle \overrightarrow{S}(x,t) \right\rangle=\frac{nE_0^2}{2Z_0}\hat{x}$

We finally define the intensity of the plane wave as:

$I=\left|\left\langle \overrightarrow{S}(x,t) \right\rangle\right|=\frac{nE_0^2}{2Z_0} \sim E_0^2=\left|\overrightarrow{E}(x,t)\right|^2$

All of this makes sense to me.

$ $

In the general case however we have a generic complex signal $\overrightarrow{E}(t)$ and we define its intensity to be:

$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(\overrightarrow{E}(t) \cdot \overrightarrow{E^*}(t)\right)\text{d}t=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left|\overrightarrow{E}(t)\right|^2\text{d}t$

where $\overrightarrow{E^*}$ is the complex conjugate of $\overrightarrow{E}$ (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_(signal_processing) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density).

My question is: **are the two notions of intensity connected in some way?**

$ $

My attempt:

In the general case we have a wave packet of the form:

$E(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(\omega)e^{-i\omega t}\text{d}\omega$

where $g(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} E(t)e^{i\omega t}\text{d}t$ is the Fourier transform of $E(t)$. The power spectrum of the wave packet is given by $G(\omega)=|g(\omega)|^2$, and represents the intensity per unit frequency of the packet. In fact $E(t)$ can be seen as the superposition of infinitely many monochromatic plane waves $g(\omega)e^{-i\omega t}$, and $G(\omega)$ represents the intensity of each of them, as seen above, because $g(\omega)$ represents the amplitude of each of them. Then the total intensity of the packet is given by:

$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} G(\omega)\text{d}\omega=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |E(t)|^2\text{d}t$

by using Plancherel theorem, then finding the previous definition of intensity. Am I totally wrong? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Integral of $|E|^2$ wrt time does not seem to have the same units as intensity?

Comment: Yes, it's true, I'm ignoring a moltiplicative constant, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_(signal_processing)

Comment: Something is weird. I just skimmed through your question, but the spectral integral or the time integral is the Energy contained in the wavepacket, not it's intensity. Intensity is $\propto\left| E \right| ^2$. (Edit, actually intensity requires the definition of $E(\vec{r},t)$ in its full extent, as its Power/area. When ignoring space, then $\left|E(t) \right|^2$ is power definition)